# jQM ui-hidden-accessible doesn't hide parent div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

```
<div id="foo">
   <input type="text" id="myinput" class="ui-hidden-accessible">
   <a href="#" onclick="myFunc()" data-role="button">Bar</a>
   <ul id="search" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search 1" ></ul>
   <ul id="search2" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search2" ></ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to completely hide the input field, but jquery mobile adds an ugly div around it which is 100% width of page and 2px high (grey). Is it possible to hide it with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data-wrapper-class` attribute to apply any custom classes any `input` type.

```
<input type="text" data-wrapper-class="ui-hidden-accessible custom-style">
```

The classes will be added to parent div of the input.

Answer (score 2):

**With jQuery:**
Because jQM always wraps the input with just one dive, you can do this:

```
$("#myinput").parent().hide();
```

**With data-role:**
If you add `data-role="none"` to the input, jQM will not apply the styles.

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" class="ui-hidden-accessible" data-role="none">
```